# Does .NET 6 Allow Multiple Apps to run in a Single App Pool?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0, application-pool, asp.net-core-6.0

Does .NET 6 allow multiple apps to run in a single app pool?

.NET Core did not, but I'm not finding anywhere that specifies if .NET 6 allows this?

Comment: Nothing has changed [Hosting multiple .net core using the same application pool with AspNetCoreModuleV2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635664/hosting-multiple-net-core-using-the-same-application-pool-with-aspnetcoremodule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 6 is current LTS version of .NET Core ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72240581/2501279), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955459/is-net-core-net-framework-5)) and nothing has changed in terms of app pools for [in-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#differences-between-in-process-and-out-of-process-hosting) of ASP.NET Core in the 6th version:

> - Sharing an app pool among apps isn't supported. Use one app pool per app.

Comment: But if out-of-process hosting is used, then multiple apps can run in a single pool since .NET Core 1.0.

Comment: @LexLi yes. But based on _".NET Core did not,"_ from OP it is safe to assume that in-process is used.

Comment: OP here. I actually don't understand when to or not to choose in-process hosting. Any advice or things to steer away from?

Comment: You can refer to this link about In-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core: [In-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [Out-of-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).